How to Implement Role-Based User Registration in Next.js with Prisma?
I'm building a Next.js app where users can register as either a buyer or seller. I have three roles: Buyer, Seller, and Admin. During the registration process, users can select whether they are a buyer or seller, and this information needs to be saved to the database. I'm using Prisma as my ORM.
I want to know the best practices for handling role-based registration and redirection in Next.js. For example, after users register, I want to redirect them to different dashboards depending on whether they are a buyer or seller. Additionally, what’s the best way to handle role-based permissions for accessing different parts of the app (e.g., buyers should only access the buyer dashboard)?n

Does this help? What have you tried already? Or are you just looking for theory regarding RBAC?
https://medium.com/@chsherryy/implementing-role-based-access-control-in-next-js-next-auth-with-prisma-and-mongodb-324f1929cf93
